# generate static urls automatically in MEANjs project

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I am working on a MEANjs project. Till now, the project consisted of dynamic urls, wherein the city and country name will get attached to the url and filters will attach as parameters, dynamically. But now, for SEO purpose, I need static urls with filters and city/country name.

Currently I have urls like this: www.abc.com/xyz/san-jose--ca--usa?params=123

I need to have static urls for the same as: www.abc.com/123-xyz-in-san-jose--ca--usa

So here are the problems I am facing:
1. I am not sure whether this has to done in backend(nodejs) or frontend(angularjs).
2. Whether I need to generate and store all such 1000s of url somewhere in my project.
3. if point 2 is true, do I need a list of all cities and countries to generate such urls? If so, how will I get those.

I tried to google, but I could only find something in php which is .htaccess and I am not even sure if its the same thing that I am searching.

Can somebody help me out or guide me to any documentation explaining the same?

**Edit:**
Since I need to use google maps geocode to get lat-lon for the city-state combo. For point 1, I am going the angularjs way. I can specify the routes similar to the way suggested by [Molda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3284355/molda) in angularjs.
For point 2, I figured I will have to generate the static links for all city-state combinations and store it in some file. But I am not sure how to get all the city-state combination for USA.
As of now, I am going with [census data](http://census.gov). But again, not sure if google will geocode it correctly or not. If anybody can help me out in this, it will be awesome.

Comment: In Express you can create route for this like so `app.get('/xyz/:country/:state/:city/:params',...` and access them like so `req.params.country` or `req.params.city` etc. The URL would be `www.abc.com/xyz/usa/ca/san-jose/123` hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess same can be done in angularjs routes too. Also, since I have to geocode the state-city combo via google geocoding api to fetch data according to the coordinates I get, I am assuming I have to do all this in the front end itself.

Comment: Yes the same can be done in angular and in your case it's probably even better

Comment: Thanks for the help!!